# How to avoid destroying an object on assignment / returning

Tags: c++

This is an example class:

```
struct peel {
    int* p;
    bool nodelete;
    peel() { 
        nodelete = false; 
    }
    ~peel() {
        if (!nodelete) delete p;
    }
    peel& operator=(const peel& other) {
        p = other.p;
        nodelete = true;
    }
};

struct banana {
    peel getPeel() {
        peel ret;
        ret.p = new int();
        return ret;
    }
};
```

So when I call

```
banana peelSource;
auto myPeel = peelSource.getPeel();
```

I don't get to use myPeel because somewhere between return and assignment the destructor of the peel object gets called and while the pointer is copied over, the allocated memory is gone and thus invalid pointer.

Why I want to create the object like this:

1. In my actual class, banana contains a lot of information essential to the creation of peel and overall its easier just to have banana build the peel.
2. I don't want to allocate a peel with new and return a pointer because for one I like the ease of the peel getting automatically destroyed once it goes out of scope and also, peel has a bracket operator which is much nicer without having to dereference the peel in brackets first.

The assignment operator is my attempt to avoid deleting stuff but its never called, not sure if I did that right.

Anyways, how do I make auto myPeel = peelSource.getPeel(); work without having it delete the data?

Comment: I love code that is destined to have a memory leak.

Comment: Please read up on smart pointers

Comment: You violated the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)). You have a custom destructor and custom assignment operator, but no custom copy constructor. The `return` statement uses the copy constructor to copy `peel` to the caller. The default custom copy constructor is a shallow copy. This means that both the original and the copy have the same value of `p`, and they both have `nodelete = false`, which means that both will try to delete `p` at destruction. The `peel` destructs first, deleting `p`. That leaves the copy with a dangling pointer.

Comment: The way you designed your code, it will end up with a dangling pointer. Probably what you wanted to do was for the assignment operator (and copy constructor) to set the *other* object's `nodelete` to false. Which would work but there are better solutions.

Comment: Your explanations do not make a convincing point for why you'd want to use dynamic allocation for this task at all.

Answer (score 1):

You write:

> I don't want to allocate a peel with new and return a pointer because for one I like the ease of the peel getting automatically destroyed once it goes out of scope and also, peel has a bracket operator which is much nicer without having to dereference the peel in brackets first.

You might consider the following. Start by writing `peel` with the interface you want (e.g., the bracket operator). Hold everything as regular value members, without the pointers, boolean flags indicating no deleteion, and so forth.

```
struct peel
{
    /* Hold here everything as regular value members, without 
    pointers or boolean flags indicating whether to delete, and
    so forth.*/

    // Here's your brackets operator.
    ... operator[](...);
};
```

Now just use this

```
struct banana
{
    peel getPeel() {
        peel ret;
        ...
        return ret;
    }
};
```

Profile to see if there's any problem using this. There's a fairly good chance there won't be, due to [*NRVO*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

*If*, for some reason, you find that you can't manipulate `peel` objects by value efficiently, then consider refactoring as follows. First, move all heavy parts to `peel_imp` (again avoiding the pointers and boolean flags).

```
// "Heavy" peel stuff.
struct peel_imp
{
    /* Hold here everything as regular value members, without 
    pointers or boolean flags indicating whether to delete, and
    so forth.*/
};
```

Then, as @EdHeal suggests in the comments, use a smart pointer to hold the implementation.

```
struct peel
{
    ... operator[](...);

    std::shared_ptr<peel_imp> m_imp;
};
```

Again making `peel` objects efficient for value manipulation.

Comment: @M.M I completely agree, however I don't see where my answer contained code whose correctness relied on elision or not. My point only regarded performance.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Thanks for the comment. That was not the idea of the answer, but I see why it is not apparent. Will update.

Answer (score 0):

Why to destroy the object on assignment and return. It'll be invalid pointer and useless.
Better option is use move constructor/ Move assignment operator.